# Find a stolen Samsung Galaxy Tab E

Tags: google-account, location-services

I gotten involved in an incident that i got my tab stolen. I have not used the device for so long and i have some personal details on the device.

The problem I have now in trying to recover this devices is that I am not sure I have enabled GPS tracking on the device.

The only lead I have on this device now is that my G-mail account is logged unto it and also my Google play store is logged unto it. Please is it still possible for either locate this device or remotely wipe it? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Did you had mobile data enabled at the moment of theft?

Answer (score 1):

By logging into your [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/), you can select "GET STARTED" under "Find your phone".

[image: Find your phone.]

As long as the missing device is still logged into your Google account, it should show on the list on the next screen where you can tap on it for additional steps. From there, you can attempt to locate, lock or wipe the device.

[image]